# Can geth and eth share the same accounts and blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, go-ethereum, clients, accounts, cpp-ethereum

It appears when I have multiple ethereum clients installed, that they all have their own data, accounts and even their own copy of the blockchain.

Is it possible to share accounts and the blockchain accross multiple clients somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, different implementations are not inherently compatible with each other's data structures. Although clients may share some similarities either accidentally or intentionally, most non-consensus development was done in isolation.

Two major exceptions to this exist:

- keys adhering to the [Web3 Secret Storage Definition](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Web3-Secret-Storage-Definition) should be transportable between `eth` and `geth` clients
- the mining datafile is stored at a [shared location](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Backup-&-restore#data-directory)